# Is "intend on" ungrammatical?

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

Is **"intend on"** ungrammatical?

I thought that "*intend to do something*" and "*intend on doing something*" were synonymous, but I was told by a few people that "intend on" is ungrammatical and is a common mistake, yet I see it being used in novels by authors.
Is it really ungrammatical?

Comment: https://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2017/03/intend-on.html  It seems to depend who you ask.  Most consider it to be *colloquial*.  I don't think I would say it.

Comment: I encounter that usage all the time, and consider it to be perfectly natural.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that 'intend to' is probably more formally correct, while 'intend on' is more colloquial. It might also depend on where the person you ask is from.

I personally think 'intend on' sounds more southern, but I could be wrong. But, if I'm right, a Southerner (or someone raised by Southerners) would probably think it formally correct.